# Why doesn't php's $_COOKIE read cookies synchronously?

Tags: php, cookies

In my php app (no specific framework) I have a page with one required file where I am storing a cookie (using [js cookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie) ) depending on the url - as in

**child.php**

```
<?
// some PHP code
?>

<!-- some HTML/JS code -->
<script>
Cookies.set('c', window.location.pathname);

$('.el').on('click', {
window.location = "/parent.php?path=pathname" // this reloads the parent so it can reload the parent and process the previously stored cookie as well as handling other features are displayed based on `path GET parameter`
});
</script>

?>
```

Then I want to show (use) the cookie in the newly loaded page (and parent of child.php) in PHP code as in

**parent.php**

```
 require_once("child.php"); // including the file here is supposed to process the cookie store logic, which indeed (on the frontend side) does
 if($_COOKIE['c'] = 'xyz') { //etc. }
```

but $_COOKIE['c'] is empty when printing it to `error_log` (as if the newly stored cookie wasn't there), whereas after reloading the cookie is displayed correctly (hence why I am assuming it is correctly fetching the cookie but that cookie is available **asynchronously**)

**Why?**

---

**UPDATE**: headers (Cookies) the browser sends when opening the page the first time right after you click that element (and page reloads)

> no cookie "c"

when re-opening the page from the link

> c:xyz

the same applies if clicking the link twice (which itself triggers `location.reload`)

The header `cache-control` is set to `no-cache`

So what I see happening is that $_COOKIE['c'] returns an empty string because on first load that http cookie is not available, but how can I have it available without having to reload **twice**?

Comment: Might be a typo here, but `if($_COOKIE['c'] = 'xyz')` assigns a value, it's not comparing it.

Comment: yes a typo (only on SO)

Comment: For the future, try and copy/paste as much as possible from your real code and not to rewrite code here, if possible, since it's easy to accidentally introduce new issues, or even unknowingly solve it with a typo.

Comment: Check your browser dev tools network tab and show exactly **all the headers** the browser sends right after you click that element (and page reloads).

Comment: @zerkms added in my original question

Comment: @dragonmnl unless your page is cached - then as long as the cookie is sent - it will be available through `$_COOKIE['c']`. Take `curl`, create a request without and with cookie and see that the latter always renders correctly.

Comment: @zerkms not sure what you mean?  I don't think my page is cached ( The header `cache-control` is set to `no-cache` )

Comment: @dragonmnl if it's not cached then `$_COOKIE['c']` would be filled as long as the cookie header is set. Either that, or you oversimplified your code to a degree when the problem is not reproducible. If you recreate your script to be as simple as what you posted you'll see it works just fine.

Comment: just to make sure I understand your point: the issue is in fact that the page is cached which is **why the cookie is not sent**?

Comment: @dragonmnl as you checked already - it is sent. If it's sent - then the script would see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the page is served for the first time - the cookie **IS NOT SET YET**.

The steps are the following:

1. The page fully renders (cookie was not set yet)
2. Browser evaluates the page, including JS, that sets the cookie
3. You refresh the page, now the cookie is set - hence a browser sends it in the request and php on the server side sees it.

So the problem is that step 1 happens much earlier than the step 2, it has nothing to do with synchronicity.

Comment: makes sense. however window.location is called directly after setting cookie so I would assume at the moment the page is showed (after loading child.php) the cookie was set but in fact is not (until I don't refresh manually - e.g. the 2nd time). any idea?

Comment: If I understand your code correctly, you are creating a page which sets a cookie; reloads itself; checks if that cookie is set (from the previous load) and does some stuff: How is this code not causing the page to go into an infinite reload loop?

Comment: in fact the "reload page" is triggered a on a click, so it's not always executed. I will now edit my question to better clarify